# How do I match beginning/end of string in regex?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I know that there's `^` and `$` but those are for the beginning and end of *line*, I am trying to match the beginning and end of *string*/word.

I tried to use `\b`, which didn't work. For example:

```
echo "lol llol" | grep -E \blol
```

Comment: You probably need to protect the ``\`` from interpretation by your shell - either `'\blol'` or `\\blol`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either of these, depending on what you're trying to display:

```
$ echo "lol llol" | grep -E "\blol"
lol llol

$ echo "lol llol" | grep -Eo "\blol"
lol
```

Putting the regex in quotes solves your matching problem.  The `-o` flag causes grep to only print the matched string instead of the entire line.

Comment: I thought about my grep command being wrong, but couldn't figure out I should have put them in quotes, that usually defeats the purpose of backslash.